# Object not following Nurbs path as expected

Tags: animation

I made a Nurbs path and set the object constraint on the ball to "follow path" then hit "animate Path". [image]the ball has a blue line connecting it to the path instead of it being "on" the path. Also, it is going backward from the end to the beginning. How can I get the ball on the path and have it begin at the start?
Thank you
Dean[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it’s offset from the curve, likely by its own position. Set the object’s position to zeroes in the Properties editor -> Object tab and see what happens.

Second off, you can either reverse the direction of the animation (either by manually animating the offset yourself or probably just moving the existing auto-created key frames in the dope sheet), or you can go into edit mode on the curve and use the Reverse Direction operator after selecting all.

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question.

Comment: @DeanDoeling PTL! Your welcome, please click the check mark next to the answer, as it helps my rep. Thx.